# RMSECV monotonically increasing - interpretation?

Tags: cross-validation, partial-least-squares, rms

I used partial least squares regression (no intercept) with 10-fold cross validation and my RMSECV monotonically increases as shown below:

[image: RMSECV plot]

I cannot find any literature on this phenomenon - does it mean that there is no relationship between the predictor variables and response?

Comment: It seems adding latent variables hurt the model. Maybe, there is no linear relation, did you try using regularised regression models?

Comment: Actually the response variable is a vector of one's (one-class classification)... so it's not clear there is a linear relation.

Comment: Maybe you can try One-class SVM. This is available in many SVM packages. For example kernlab in R.

Comment: Well, the RMSECV of the first LV seems to be fairly good. A single LV may be enough to explain the dependent variables almost perfectly in terms of covariance so that anything else is "noise. Did you validate the model (only 1 LV model) with an independent test set? If so, what was the RMSEP value or misclassification rate?

Comment: I think it is because my data was naturally with zero mean and for one-class PLS this is problematic. I was able to use one-class SVM and this seemed to work better (or as expected). The evaluation set and the test set were different in their means, so I did not catch this before (and predictions with 1 LV returned values but were not useful with missclassification rate of 50% or so - basically random).